# Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint

Tags: docker

Nao consigo subir nenhum container na minha maquina, no console informa esse erro:
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint quero-boot-redis-1 (1de8a9bf187a7bfccc0f526db1924b83cf3064de6007fad02ddadddff14bda5b): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:6379: bind: address already in use

Estou tentando subir usando esse comando para fazer teste:

docker compose run opa-client bash

tenntei rodar esse comando:

`/etc/init.d/redis-server stop retorno:` Stopping redis-server (via systemctl): redis-server.service.`

sudo systemctl stop redis-server
`
Mas nenhum desses comandos está permitinho subir novamente o container, e no terminal mostra que esses servidores foram pausados. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Bem-vinda ao Stack Overflow. A mensagem de erro diz que já tem um serviço na sua máquina rodando na porta 6379. Mas este é o fórum errado para perguntas em Português, vc pode obter ajuda aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/